# javascript includes problems and pitfalls

Tags: javascript

What kind of problems and pitfalls can one encounter while doing javascript includes (`<script src="sample.js" type="text/javascript><script>`) and how to avoid them?

I'm asking this because I just ran into an issue where I wrote my javascript code inside a velocity template file which is included in an overall layout template. The layout template has many different javascript included. My javascript code works just fine on a page by itself, but when included with the layout template, it started to break. (No javascript errors, but things weren't working).

Comment: This is a very generic question. You might want to be more specific about what you are doing, and what results you are seeing; it's pretty hard to give a good answer to such a generic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you're having a collision of global objects. your best bet in this scenario is to move all your code into a namespace, by which I mean create an object or anonymous function to house the javascript code you've written.

for example instead of just doing

```
var myWord = 'hello!';
alert(myWord);
```

where the name `myWord` might already be in use, you could do

```
(function() {
    var myWord = 'hello!';
    alert(myWord);
})();
```

or if you need things to persist,

```
var myUniqueNamespace = new (function() {
    this.myWord = 'hello!';
})();
alert(myUniqueNamespace.myWord);
```

where you only need to ensure that `myUniqueNamespace` is indeed a unique name, and you can add whatever names you like as properties to it.

re closure comment: not quite, but we can make it one like this

```
var myUniqueNamespace = new (function() {
    var myWord = 'hello!';
    this.sayWord = function() { return myWord; };
})();
alert(myUniqueNamespace.sayWord());
```

`myWord` exists within the scope of the anonymous function used to create `myUniqueNamespace`, so you can't get do it directly from the outside (similar to a private member in other languages). however the method `sayWord` is defined in the same scope as `myWord` and closes over it, meaning that access to `myWord` is maintained within the method defintion. that might not be the clearest explanation but I hope the example makes it clear.

Comment: Is your example of doing var myUniqueNamesapce = new (function(){//code})();  what they called 'closure'?